# Let $\sigma\in S_n$. Then, $\sigma x=x\iff$ the only orbit of $x$ by certain group action is trivial.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, symmetric-groups

I'm reading the proof for the following statement:

> Every permutation is a product of pairwaise disjoint cycles, and this descomposition is unique up to the order of terms.

At the beginning of the proof, it says:

> Given $\sigma\in S_n$ (symmetric group), let $\mathbb{Z}$ act on $X=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ by $m\bullet x=\sigma^m x$ $\left(\sigma x=\sigma(x)\right)$. It is indeed a group action. Then $X$ partitions $X$ into orbits. We see that $\sigma x=x$ the orbit of $x$ is trivial.

Just in case: the **orbit** of $x\in X$ is the set $G\bullet x=\mathcal O_x=\{g\bullet x:g \in G\}$ (if $\bullet$ is a left group action of $G$ on $X$).

That last statement is my doubt: $\sigma x=x$ iff l the orbit of $ x$  is trivial.

I thought about the following: If $\sigma x=x$, $x$ is a fixed point of the permutation $\sigma$. Then, $\sigma^nx=x~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ which implies $\mathbb{Z}\bullet x=\{x\}$. Conversely, if the orbit is trivial, $\sigma^n x=x~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, in particular, $\sigma^1 x=\sigma x=x$.

Was my reasoning right? I mean, a fixed point of a permutation will be a fixed point "forever"? (In the sense of applying over and over the same permutation). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning it is correct

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, though I'd have found neater to saying that the cycle structure of $\sigma\in S_n$ pops up when considering the natural action of $\langle\sigma\rangle$ on $X$, which makes your argument even better fitting in. And the fixed points of $\sigma$ (and hence of all the elements of $\langle\sigma\rangle$) correspond to the "break points" between adjacent round brackets in the cycle notation of $\sigma$, namely: "$\dots)(\dots$".